# Count number of unique names per ID and write result in new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby, unique

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    "id": ["K0", "K0", "K0", "K1", "K1", "K2", "K2","K2"],
    "name": ["Peter", "Peter", "Max", "Jim", "Jim", "Lucy", "Jack","Pam"],
    }
    ) 

df
```

For each `id` I want to find the number of unique names `num_dist_names`:

[image]

This means, the `id` with `K0` has 2 unique names: Peter and Max

[image]

Comment: @anky thanks, just looking for dupe.

Comment: Use `df['num_dist_names'] = df.groupby('id')['name'].transform('nunique')`